# I want to assign onclick function to buttons like this, but it not work, why?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I want to assign onclick function to buttons like this

```
window.onload = function() {
  var tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    console.log(tablinks[i].innerText);
    tablinks[i].onclick = openCity(event,tablinks[i].innerText);
  }
}



function openCity(evt,cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    console.log(cityName);
    // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active"};
```

I see that when window loads it send logs to console:

> London panel.js:4:11 London panel.js:14:9 Paris panel.js:4:11 Paris panel.js:14:9 Tokyo panel.js:4:11 Tokyo panel.js:14:9

But when i click button onclick does not fire. Why?

Comment: can you add HTML too, that would help addressing your issue.

Comment: type:
`tablinks[i].onclick = function(event) { openCity(event,tablinks[i].innerText);}`

Comment: missing function, onlick should be function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues, first declare the variable (*i*) with [**`let`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) to create ***a block scope*** for the variable and call the function inside of an anonymous function.

**Demo:**

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (let i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].onclick = function(){openCity(event,tablinks[i].innerText)};
  }
}
function openCity(e, text){
  console.log(text);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="tablinks">tab1</li>
  <li class="tablinks">tab2</li>
  <li class="tablinks">tab3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! Will read what anonymous function is. Everything work right now.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the function by doing: `tablinks[i].onclick = openCity(event,tablinks[i].innerText);`

Instead you could pass the function as a variableand get the city name from the currentTarget on the event.

Example:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    console.log(tablinks[i].innerText);
    tablinks[i].onclick = openCity;
  }
};

  function openCity(evt) {
    const cityName = evt.currentTarget.innerText;
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    console.log(cityName);
    // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
      tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
      tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active"
  };
```

```html
<button class="tablinks">TEST</button>
<div class="tablinks">TAB CONTENT</div>
<div id="TEST">TEST CITY</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are already invoking the function and setting the returned value as a property value of `onclick` property since it's not returning anything(would be `undefined`) nothing will assign to `onclick` handler.

So instead wrap the function with an anonymous function as use its reference as `onclick` handler. In addition to that initialize `i` as `let` to keep the value in the block context.

```
var tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (let i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        console.log(tablinks[i].innerText);
        tablinks[i].onclick = function(event) { openCity(event,tablinks[i].innerText); }
    }

}
```